# Impact of creating separate indexes on high-insertion PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, performance, index

I'm building a taxi application that uses PostgreSQL as the database backend. One of the tables, `taxi_order`, has the following columns: `start_address`, `country_id`, `taxi_fleet_id`, and `driver_id`.

Considering the expected load of approximately 100 new taxi orders per second in different countries, completed by different taxi fleets and drivers, I am wondering about the potential impact of creating separate indexes on the `country_id`, `taxi_fleet_id`, and `driver_id` columns.

My goal is to optimize query performance for filtering and joining operations, as well as to perform regular statistical calculations on the `taxi_order` table.

Given this scenario, I have the following questions:

1. Will creating separate indexes on the `country_id`, `taxi_fleet_id`, and `driver_id` columns significantly decrease insertion performance due to the high insertion rate?
2. What factors should I consider when assessing the impact on insertion performance?
3. Are there any strategies or best practices to minimize the impact on insertion performance while maintaining efficient query performance?
4. How can I optimize the index design and database configuration to strike a balance between insertion performance and query performance?

**Any insights, recommendations, or experiences related to optimizing high-insertion tables and maintaining good query performance in PostgreSQL would be greatly appreciated.**

### Full table definition

```
                                               Table "public.taxi_order"
            Column             |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default                 
-------------------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+----------------------------------------
 id                            | bigint                   |           | not null | nextval('taxi_order_id_seq'::regclass)
 status_id                     | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 passenger_id                  | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 driver_id                     | bigint                   |           |          | 
 vehicle_id                    | bigint                   |           |          | 
 ordered_vehicle_category_id   | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 country_region_id             | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 payment_type_id               | bigint                   |           | not null | 
 payment_status_id             | bigint                   |           |          | 
 taxi_fleet_id                 | bigint                   |           |          | 
 passenger_promotion_id        | bigint                   |           |          | 
 promo_code_id                 | bigint                   |           |          | 
 code                          | text                     |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 order_number                  | text                     |           |          | 
 created_ts                    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 accepted_ts                   | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 arrived_ts                    | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 pickup_ts                     | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 completion_ts                 | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 cancellation_ts               | timestamp with time zone |           |          | 
 mileage                       | numeric                  |           |          | 
 estimated_price               | numeric                  |           | not null | 
 estimated_promotion_discount  | numeric                  |           | not null | 0
 estimated_promo_code_discount | numeric                  |           | not null | 0
 estimated_mileage             | numeric                  |           | not null | 0
 price                         | numeric                  |           |          | 
 promotion_discount            | numeric                  |           |          | 
 promo_code_discount           | numeric                  |           |          | 
 platform_fee                  | numeric                  |           |          | 
 taxi_fleet_fee                | numeric                  |           |          | 
 create_ip_address             | text                     |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "taxi_order_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "taxi_order_code_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (code)
    "taxi_order_driver_id_idx" btree (driver_id)
    "taxi_order_passenger_id_idx" btree (passenger_id)
    "taxi_order_status_region_id_idx" btree (status_id, country_region_id)
    "taxi_order_taxi_fleet_id_idx" btree (taxi_fleet_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "taxi_order_country_region_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (country_region_id) REFERENCES country_region(id)
    "taxi_order_driver_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (driver_id) REFERENCES driver(id)
    "taxi_order_ordered_vehicle_category_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (ordered_vehicle_category_id) REFERENCES vehicle_category(id)
    "taxi_order_passenger_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (passenger_id) REFERENCES passenger(id)
    "taxi_order_passenger_promotion_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (passenger_promotion_id) REFERENCES passenger_promotion(id)
    "taxi_order_payment_status_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (payment_status_id) REFERENCES taxi_order_payment_status(id)
    "taxi_order_payment_type_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (payment_type_id) REFERENCES taxi_order_payment_type(id)
    "taxi_order_promo_code_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (promo_code_id) REFERENCES passenger_promo_code(id)
    "taxi_order_status_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES taxi_order_status(id)
    "taxi_order_taxi_fleet_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_fleet_id) REFERENCES taxi_fleet(id)
    "taxi_order_vehicle_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (vehicle_id) REFERENCES vehicle(id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "driver_activity_history" CONSTRAINT "driver_activity_history_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "driver_balance_transaction" CONSTRAINT "driver_balance_transaction_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "driver_taxi_order_lock" CONSTRAINT "driver_taxi_order_lock_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "passenger_taxi_order_lock" CONSTRAINT "passenger_taxi_order_lock_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_address" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_address_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_dispatch_request" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_dispatch_request_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_driver_data" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_driver_data_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_driving_speed" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_driving_speed_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_feedback_option_map" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_feedback_option_map_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_passenger_data" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_passenger_data_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_pause" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_pause_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_route" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_route_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
    TABLE "taxi_order_suggested_route" CONSTRAINT "taxi_order_suggested_route_taxi_order_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (taxi_order_id) REFERENCES taxi_order(id)
```

Example queries:

```
SELECT t.* FROM taxi_order t WHERE t.country_region_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

SELECT t.* FROM taxi_order t WHERE t.driver_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

SELECT t.* FROM taxi_order t WHERE t.taxi_fleet_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?
```

Comment: You should add your `taxi_order` table definition and some example queries you plan to run against it. Proper index advisement will be directly based on these things.

Comment: Having another index will slow down the insertion.  But not by nearly as much as needing an index but not having it will slow down the queries.  The answer to everything else is pretty much "it depends".

Comment: Added full table definition and example queries as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WHERE t.country_region_id = ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?

Based on your queries, you would want to add "id" as a 2nd column to each of your single-column indexes.  That way it can read the rows already in the requested order (within the given equality condition) and stop once it obtained the needed limit+offset.  With your existing indexes, it would need to read all rows meeting the equality condition and then sort them.

Designing another column into an index which would exist anyway is generally a low cost thing. It doesn't increase the number of indexes which need to be maintained.  However, it could generate increased IO and reduced cachability by making the index be larger (both because the extra column needs to be stored in the index, and by defeating the duplicate compression logic recently added to btree indexes)